# Error : Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: express, body-parser

This is my error!.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newTask')
at C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\app.js:36:22
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at serveStatic (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\pruth\Desktop\ToDoList\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

This is my javascript code.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();

//variables
var items = [];

// set up view engine
app.set('view engine' , "ejs");

// set up BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// set up public files
app.use( express.static('public'));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  var today = new Date();

  var options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long"
  };

  var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  
  res.render("list" , {ejsday : day, ejsitem : items});
  
});

app.post("/", function (res,req) {

 var item = req.body.newTask;
 items.push(item);
 res.redirect("/");

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

This is my EJS code

```
        <ul>
           <li><%=ejsitem%></li>
        </ul>

        <form action="/" method="post">

             <input type="text" name="newTask">
             <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
        </form>
```

Please help.!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `app.post("/", function (res,req) {` to `app.post("/", function (req,res) {`

**Edit: Adding some details**

According to the [API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), the first param always contain request `req`, then response `res`.

So change first param `res` to `req`